# PCI wifi card suddenly stopped working

Tags: wifi, pci

My PCI Wi-Fi card suddenly stopped working after 15 days of uptime. Any ideas?

```
# ip a
26: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:63:00:00:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# ifup wlp1s0
May 24 08:03:03 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 24 08:03:05 calleva kernel: [1372635.754442] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000062]
May 24 08:03:08 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: Could not set interface wlp1s0 flags (UP): Input/output error
May 24 08:03:08 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlp1s0' UP
May 24 08:03:08 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp1s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
May 24 08:03:08 calleva kernel: [1372637.810412] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000062]
May 24 08:03:08 calleva kernel: [1372637.810434] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
May 24 08:03:10 calleva kernel: [1372639.858349] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000062]
May 24 08:03:12 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: Could not set interface wlp1s0 flags (UP): Input/output error
May 24 08:03:12 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlp1s0' UP
May 24 08:03:12 calleva wpa_supplicant[1056247]: wlp1s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
May 24 08:03:12 calleva kernel: [1372641.902346] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000062]
May 24 08:03:12 calleva kernel: [1372641.902360] ieee80211 phy2: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)

# lspci -nnk
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5392]
        Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:f053]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci

# lsmod | grep rt2
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             24576  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib             139264  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              69632  5 rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800pci,rt2800lib
mac80211              995328  6 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib,rtlwifi,rt2800lib
cfg80211              983040  3 rt2x00lib,rtlwifi,mac80211
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
```

Have tried

```
# echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove
# sleep 1
# echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

Comment: is it always *after 15 days of uptime*?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot? WiFi cards are known to malfunction at runtime due to e.g. overheating or errors in firmware.